# document.querySelectorAll([classname]) not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, getelementsbyclassname

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE9 equivalent of querySelectorAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171247/ie9-equivalent-of-queryselectorall)

I'm trying to get all elements with the classname "video" in some JS running in IE9.  I'm using `var videopanels = document.querySelectorAll(".video");` which is working great in Chrome.

Unfortunately I'm getting this error when I watch `document.querySelectorAll(".video")` in the debugger:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".video")
Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelectorAll'
Error
```

However, when I watch `document` in the debugger (it shows up as a `DispHTMLDocument`) and open up the `[Methods]` list, I see

```
querySelectorAll()
querySelectorAll(v)
IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
```

What's going on?  How come I can see it in the debugger, but not (apparently) actually call or use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your doctype to html5 standards.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Also check IE9 isn't operating in compatibility mode as this may cause it to ignore some methods it supports.

Comment: My doctype is exactly that.

Comment: It turned out my browser had got switched to IE7 compatibility mode.  I don't remember doing this but that's almost certainly the problem.  Thanks though!

Comment: Yes, it needs to be in standard mode :) No probs

Comment: @AndrewWyld Please check this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13287226/1169519).

Comment: It wasn't the actual cause of my problem, so I thought I would leave them the same because it might help people to know both possible causes.

Comment: @RobinJonsson are you OK if I change your post to reflect the IE7 thing?

Comment: Yes thanks! I forgot to add that

Comment: Fixed a problem for me in Chrome on Linux.